# Can't refresh data in p-table after deleting row ( PrimeNg )

Tags: angular, primeng

> I m using primeng 8.1 with angular 8 
>     I refer my p-table with #dt then i call dt.reset() and getcandidates() to refresh
>   But it shows first page of p-table without refreshing list i searched in official 
>       documentation but 
>       i don't find a solution so the only way to refresh data is to reload entire navigator page

```
<p-table #dt  
[paginator]="true"
[columns] = "cols"
[value]="listcandidats"
[totalRecords]="listcandidats.length"
[paginator]="true"
[rows]="5"
[style.top.px]="screenHeight/6"
>

<ng-template pTemplate="caption">
<div style="text-align: right">        
    <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
    <input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Recherche multioption" 
(input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" style="width:auto">
</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
    <th>Candidat</th>

   <th>Action</th>
    </tr>


</ng-template>
<ng-template  pTemplate="body" let-rowData >
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" >


      <td [style.width.px]="screenWidth/8"> <h3>{{rowData.nom}}</h3></td>


        <td>
     <button pButton type="button" label="modifier" (click)="showDialog(rowData.id)" class="ui- 
     button-rounded ui-button-warning">
    </button>

    <button pButton type="button" label="supprimer" 
    (click)="deletecandidat(rowData.id);dt.reset();getcandidats()" class="ui-button-rounded ui- 
    button-danger"></button>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <hr [style.width.px]="screenWidth">
   </ng-template>


   </p-table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) Document

Table may need to be aware of changes in its value in some cases such as reapplying sort. For the sake of performance, this is only done when the reference of the value changes meaning a setter is used instead of `ngDoCheck/IterableDiffers` which can reduce performance. So when you manipulate the value such as removing or adding an item, instead of using `array` methods such as `push`, `splice` create a new array reference using a spread operator or similar.

Comment: How to do that please in my case my array data table variable is listcandidates

Comment: Create  a new list candidate and assign

Comment: I 'm sorry but i don't have the right because i have only 11 reputations less than 15 please upvote my question